# sqlalchemy + postgres asyncpg.exceptions.ForeignKeyViolationError on relationship()

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, fastapi

So far in my project I was prototyping and used sqlite with sqlalchemy.
I have a couple of tables with oneToMany relationships, all works nicely.
Now, after switching to postgres, I get the `asyncpg.exceptions.ForeignKeyViolationError` for the tables where I defined ForeignKeys.

Here is my sqlalchemy parent and child model:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .database import Base
from fastapi_users_db_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable


class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    type = Column(
        String(length=10),
        server_default="No type given",
        nullable=False,
    )

    users = relationship("User", back_populates="company")

class User(Base, SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable):
    first_name = Column(
        String(length=50),
        index=True,
        server_default="No name given",
        nullable=False,
    )

    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("company.id"), nullable=False)
    company = relationship("Company", back_populates="users")
```

When trying to register a user, I get:

```
INFO:     172.17.0.1:63534 - "POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 373, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 92, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 147, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 226, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 159, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi_users/router/register.py", line 32, in register
    created_user = await user_manager.create(user, safe=True, request=request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi_users/manager.py", line 153, in create
    created_user = await self.user_db.create(db_user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi_users_db_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 159, in create
    await self.database.execute(query, user_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 169, in execute
    return await connection.execute(query, values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 295, in execute
    return await self._connection.execute(built_query)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/backends/postgres.py", line 210, in execute
    return await self._connection.fetchval(query_str, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 645, in fetchval
    data = await self._execute(query, args, 1, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1659, in _execute
    result, _ = await self.__execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1684, in __execute
    return await self._do_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1731, in _do_execute
    result = await executor(stmt, None)
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 201, in bind_execute
asyncpg.exceptions.ForeignKeyViolationError: insert or update on table "user" violates foreign key constraint "user_company_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (company_id)=(1) is not present in table "company".
```

The Error is right, there is no column `company_id` in table `company` - only `id`.
I defined to use the value `company.id` for column `company_id` in the `user`-table.
Why is the program checking on `company_id`?

I followed this sqlalchemy documentation to define the relationships: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html
It works fine like this with sqlite.

I can see in the traceback, that it connects to the right backend (`postgres`), so does that mean, sqlalchemy is not translating the relationship in the right way for postgres?

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved - for anyone who has this problem as well:

postgres does not seem to reset the id-counter like sqlite does. Since I created test data in a script, always starting from 1 up to the range limit, I used `ids` that did not exist anymore.

To put it into my example: The `company_id` I used to create a new user plainly did not exist anymore.

This, I discovered by accident. The error message misled me completely.